# Accessing Phone app with Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I have an app that I would like to add android wear support to. I want to be able to access data from the phone on the watch and have the watch just act as a different activity that still uses the classes and methods I have in the phone app so I can basically just have the watch display the same information as the phone app just in a package that is tiny-screen friendly. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, here are the steps you'll need to take to accomplish this:

1. [Create a library module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) that'll be used by both your handheld and Wear apps.
2. Move any "classes and methods" you want to re-use into it.
3. Build your [Wear-specific UI](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/index.html), referencing that library module as appropriate.
4. Use the [Wear Data API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) to move/synchronize data between the phone and watch.

Implicit here is that you can't simply "access data from the phone on the watch"; they're two completely separate, independent Android devices, and need to be developed for accordingly.